# Can't open Serial port Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with opening a serial USB port in windows 7 over my Python code.

TeraTerm and Docklight are able to open port without any problems.

When I try to open the port it comes up with the following error

SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: WindowsError(31, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')

I need to know if I am using the right serial lib. Maybe there is one that can open it without messing with the OS.

the following code returns the error above

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM5'

ser.open()
```

The entire message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-13-882203061f11>", line 4, in <module>
    ser.open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 78, in open
    self._reconfigure_port()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 220, in _reconfigure_port
    raise SerialException("Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: %r" % ctypes.WinError())
SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: WindowsError(31, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')
```

Thanks for support

Comment: Pretty sure COM5 is not a USB port... but I could be wrong!

Comment: You are wrong. A COM port can be an USB port. There are even listed in the device manager as such. For instance USB serial port (COM1).

Answer (score 0):

This is not pyserial fault, what this lib do is act as 'bridge' between your python code and windows native code from kernel32 lib using ctypes.

My guess is that your fimware or device driver is faulty but well... WINAPI Serial api is a little buggy as well anyway.

Comment: Well observed. You are actually right, the FW of the device I want to open has changed. It was working before but after the FW design eng changed it, it doesn't open with Python anymore. I actually thought that because it is working in TeraTerm and Docklight there is a way to make it work in Python too.

Hopefully someone has an answer to my problem if not we have to change the FW again. 

Thanks